# Movie about a unicorn going to find her parents, who were turned into ice by a wizard

Tags: story-identification, movie, unicorns

In 2013, my sister and I watched a movie on Netflix about a unicorn with the name Lucky or Lucy. It was a white unicorn with pinkish hair.

The plot involved a bunch of creatures, one being a pig, going to help the unicorn find her parents, who were turned into ice by a wizard of dragon of the sort.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this movie live-action or animated? If animated, was it hand-drawn or computer-generated?

Answer (score 5):

Is this ***[Princess Lillifee and the Little Unicorn](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1986935/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (2011)...?

> In Pinkovia, Princess Lillifee and her friends are enjoying a beautiful summer. One night, however, the unicorn Rosalie appears to Lillifee in a dream and urgently asks for her help; she needs Lillifee to look after her baby Lucy. When Lillifee awakes, she discovers that Lucy has magically stepped out of her dream and is now sitting on her bed, fresh as a daisy. But what has happened to Rosalie?

From [Beta Cinema](https://www.betacinema.com/138/pid/113/Princess-Lillifee-and-the-Little-Unicorn.htm):

> **Lillifee decides to bring Lucy back to her mother. In order to find Rosalie, she sets off with the unicorn baby and her friends to the neighboring country Bluetopia. Upon their arrival, they are shocked to discover that the land has been cast under a dreadful spell! Although it's the middle of summer, it is frosty and cold, and everything is covered with ice and snow. Lillifee quickly finds out who is responsible for the disaster: Steel, the winter prince of Bluetopia. Jealous of his twin brother, the summer prince, he has frozen the country in a deep winter sleep. The enchanted ice can only be melted by the unicorns' magical powers. Steel, of course, wants to prevent this at all costs. So he has kidnapped Lucy's parents and imprisoned them in impenetrable ice.** Lucy is now Bluetopia's only hope. Steel has the baby unicorn searched for all over the country, and finds her with Lillifee. The fairy princess manages to flee at the last moment, but now she must act quickly. Lillifee can only free Bluetopia from the evil curse with Lucy's help…

The protagonist is Lillifee, the fairy princess of Pinkovia, and the plot involves her trying to reunite an infant unicorn named Lucy with her parents, who were frozen in a block of ice by Steel, the winter prince of the neighboring country of Bluetopia.

Lillifee is accompanied on her journey by Pupsi the pig and Basil the hedgehog and there are various other talking animals in the film, which is a sequel to *[Princess Lillifee](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1401245/)* (2009) and originally based on a [children's book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1500424.Princess_Lillifee) by Monika Finsterbusch.